# How to solve "cinnamon-session-cinnamon failed" error

Tags: linux-mint, login

When I start `Linux Mint 17.3` in Virtual Box environment, it always fails to GUI login.

I have to change CUI login UI by `Shift+Alt+F4`, then run `startx`.

After that everything works fine.

This is the detail of the error:

#### ~/.xsession-errors

```
    syndaemon: no process found
    /etc/mdm/Xsession: Beginning session setup...
    /etc/mdm/Xsession: Executing cinnamon-session-cinnamon failed, will try to run x-terminal-emulator
    /etc/mdm/Xsession: 205: exec: x-terminal-emulator: not found
```

How can I solve the problem?

#### ~/.profile

```
#umask 022

# if running bash
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
#       . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi

# Add $PATH
export PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/usr/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH'
```

This is my `~/.profile` file.

Comment: try `sudo apt-get install cinnamon`

Comment: I already have it. I got `cinnamon is already the newest version.`.

Comment: Did you edited the `/etc/environment` or the `/etc/profile` or the `~/.profile` file

Comment: At first I renamed `~/.profile` then I could login, so as you suggested the problem is in the file. But in the file I'm just adding new paths, I don't get why this causes an error. Am I writing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in your `~/.profile`, in this line precisely:

```
export PATH='/usr/local/bin:$PATH'
```

It should be written with double quotes:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"
```

Such a line means: define an environment variable named `PATH` whose content is `/usr/local/bin:` followed by the current value of PATH (that is `$PATH`).

If you use single quotes, the value of PATH is literally `/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and `$PATH` is no longer substituted with the current value. Basically, you are narrowing your PATH search to `/usr/local/bin` which explains why `x-terminal-emulator` is not found, among other things.